# Bad response code

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, social-media

I work a lot with helping my customers with sharing articles on Facebook. But I must admit that I have problem understanding the debugger, and I think the error codes shows little information about what the problem really is.

Check out [this article](http://www.krf.no/ikbViewer/page/krf/artikkel?p_document_id=68741&hovedtema=15105&person=34801&hva=16129).

Why is the tool returning a **502 response code**?

I have [this one](http://www.evita.no/ikbViewer/soa-bloggen/artikkel/70662/webservice-enablement-of-workflowserviceapi-using-a-spring-component) as well, where URL not reachable are displayed at my comments box.